# Best way to store processed text data for streaming to gensim?

Tags: stream, nlp, storage, gensim, word2vec

I've got several hundred pandas data frames, each of which has a column of very long strings that need to be processed/sentencized and finally tokenized before modeling with word2vec.

I can store them in any format on the disk, before I build a stream to pass them to gensim's word2vec function.

What format would be best, and why?  The most important criterion would be performance vis-a-vis training (which will take many days), but coherent structure to the filesystem would also be nice.

Would it be crazy to store several million or maybe even a few billion text files containing one sentence each?  Or perhaps some sort of database?  If this was numerical data I'd use hdf5.  But it's text.  The cleanest would be to store them in the original data frames, but that seems less ideal from an i/o perspective, because I'd have to load each data frame (largish) every epoch.

What makes the most sense here?

Answer (score 1):

As you do your preprocessing/tokenization of all the source data that you want to be part of a single training session, append the results to a single plain-text file.

Use space-separated words, and end each 'sentence' (or any other useful text-chunk that's less than 10,000 words long) with a newline.

Then you can use the `corpus_file` option for specifying your pre-tokenized training data, and will get the maximum possible multithreading benefit. (That mode will direct each thread to open its own view into a range of the single file, so there's no blocking on any distributor thread.)